# Coq: How to produce a strong polymorphic dependent type hypothesis

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic, induction, proof-of-correctness

I have been having some problems with dependent induction because a "weak hypothesis".

For example :

I have a dependent complete foldable list :

```
Inductive list (A : Type) (f : A -> A -> A) : A -> Type :=
  |Acons : forall {x x'' : A} (y' : A) (cons' : list f (f x x'')), list f (f (f x x'') y')
  |Anil : forall (x: A) (y : A), list f (f x y).
```

And a function that a return the applied fold value from inductive type list and other function that forces a computation of these values through a matching.

```
Definition v'_list {X} {f : X -> X -> X} {y : X} (A : list f y) := y.

Fixpoint fold {A : Type} {Y : A} (z : A -> A -> A) (d' : list z Y) :=
  match d' return A with
    |Acons x y => z x (@fold _ _ z y)
    |Anil _ x y  => z x y
   end.
```

Clearly, that's function return the same value if have the same dependent typed list and prove this don't should be so hard.

```
Theorem listFold_eq : forall {A : Type} {Y : A} (z : A -> A -> A) (d' : list z Y), fold d' = v'_list d'.
intros.
generalize dependent Y.
dependent induction d'.
(.. so ..)
Qed.
```

My problem is that dependent definition generates for me a weak hypothesis.

Because i have something like that in the most proof that i use dependent definitions, the problem of proof above:

```
A : Type
z : A -> A -> A
x, x'', y' : A
d' : list z (z x x'')
IHd' : fold d' = v'_list d'
______________________________________(1/2)
fold (Acons y' d') = v'_list (Acons y' d')
```

Even i have a polymorphic definition in (z x x'') i can't apply IHd' in my goal.

My question if have a way of define more "powerful" and polymorphic induction, instead of working crazy rewriting terms that sometimes struggling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
simpl.
unfold v'_list.
```

You can see that you're almost there (you can finish with rewriting), but the arguments of `z` are in the wrong order, because `list` and `fold` don't agree on the way the fold should go.

On an unrelated note, `Acons` could quantify over a single `x`, replacing `f x x''` with just `x`.